# Which algorithms do advertising servicies use to make recommendations based on geolocation history data?

Tags: machine-learning, spatial, pattern-recognition

Some mobile advertising companies (for example [xad](http://www.xad.com/company/)) state that they can "create audiences based on real-world location indicators and demographic information derived from visitation patterns".

As i understand it, such companies have my geolocation history (via some app which i use and which is part of their advertising network) and somehow they try to guess which goods/services/places i might be interested in. They also seem to approach the question of when i might be interested i.e. when it is the best time and place to show me the ad.

So i wonder which statistics/machine learning/something else technologies can be used for such predictions? Is there any common scientific name for such kind of research? Are there any widely accepted approaches?